# AppLovin Banner Ad Crash on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, applovin

I am trying to integrate AppLovin Banner Ads into my Universal App. On iPhone, it works fine. But on iPad, there is a crash of the app after the view with the banner is left/dismissed by the user.

Here is the code to show the banner ad:

```
// Create new AdView
adView = [[ALAdView alloc] initBannerAd];

//
// (Optional) Position the ad at the bottom of screen. By default
// it would be postitioned at (0,0)
//
adView.frame = CGRectMake( 0,
                          self.view.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height,
                          adView.frame.size.width,
                          adView.frame.size.height );

adView.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

// (Mandatory) Add the ad into current view
[self.view addSubview:adView];

// (Mandatory) Trigger loading of the new ad.
[adView loadNextAd];
```

If I comment out the addSubview invocation, no crash occurs. It seems like the added subview does not get unitialized or something.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: for future users... To move it on top...  adView.frame = CGRectMake( 0,
                              0,
                              adView.frame.size.width,
                              adView.frame.size.height );

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the parent controller was not specified. Adding

```
adView.parentController = self;
```

solved the problem. Here is the final code:

```
// Create new AdView
adView = [[ALAdView alloc] initBannerAd];
adView.parentController = self;

// (Optional) Position the ad at the bottom of screen.
// By default it would be postitioned at (0,0)
adView.frame = CGRectMake( 0,
                          self.view.frame.size.height - adView.frame.size.height,
                          adView.frame.size.width,
                          adView.frame.size.height );

adView.autoresizingMask =
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

// (Mandatory) Add the ad into current view
[self.view addSubview:adView];

// (Mandatory) Trigger loading of the new ad.
[adView loadNextAd];
```

Comment: "initBannerAd" is marked as deprecated now... What is updated code ?